# dojo 1.4 problems with ie7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, dojo

Tryed making an dijit.Tree from an TreestoreModel, works fine in Firefox, but the Tree dont display in IE7.
So i wanted to test the campus samples with my ie- they dont even load. (in firefox all ok)
Tested it on 2 different pcs. No Error Msg, just the Loading sun.
Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: The "CodeGlass" project to show demos on campus still doesn't work on IE, unfortunately.  That's being worked on.

Comment: Try doing a copy-paste of the full example from Firefox to a file, then load in IE.  If that doesn't work, or if you can provide a simple example of the problem you're having, you can file a bug at http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org

Answer (score 1):

Time passed fast, but finaly im back on that task.
Im not sure how the status of the campus samples, but i found the source of my problem:
the encoding of the json response.  If its not in utf8 and contains special chars, ie just dont show any tree, while firefox does.
Easy to find with google, if you know what your looking for and dont look for a dojo problem with ie, if its an json problem with ie:)